# Entity Framework Core DbContext lifecycle in Dotnet Core console app

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have .net core web api project that is using Entity Framework Core to add/edit/delete records from a DB which is working as intended.

It is configured with Dependency Injection with data access and service layers with the web api controllers interacting via the injected service layer.

This part of the solution is working absolutely fine.

However I also have a separate .net core console app that shares the same service layer and consists of a long running task that periodically polls the same data, however if a change is made to the data via the website this is not reflected in the data retrieved on each iteration in the console app.  From my research I understand this is due to the data being changed outside the DbContext.

I'm still pretty new to EF so am trying to broaden my understanding.  The web api is using a new DB context per web request which is why I am not running into the same issue as the console app and there are lots of articles and discussion on the web app side, but not so much in the context of a console app.

I believe with my 'stale' data that I'm not doing something quite right with respect to DbContext lifespan and I am hanging on to a context longer than is ideal.

Wrapping the operations around a 'using' statement I think would do what I need outside of a DI scenario, but I'm trying to understand how I can achieve the equivalent when using DI?  I have managed to get round the problem to a degree by using '.AsNoTracking' in the places where I need it, but was wondering if there is a better way?

Also, any pointers/documentation on using EF Core in a scenario where multiple systems may be accessing the same DB records would be really helpful.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can register the DbContext using Transient lifetime scope in DI container.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want a DI based approach, so I might consider creating a factory class (with interface) to create instances of DbContext (inject DbContextOptionsBuilder in the factory's constructor).  It should be able to create a new instance for you on each call.  Then inject that factory into your console.

Comment: What would be the difference between declare the context as transient and create a factory to create a new instance each call?

Comment: The only problem declaring the context as transient, is that you cannot pass attached objects between services, since if the other method tries to save the data, a problem with the contexts will arise

Comment: Factory could create as many instances of the context as was needed within a single call or execution of the console whereas I believe injecting normally as transient in a console app essentially forces it to use the same context instance which can be an issue if multiple threads are needing it (or even if you wanted to make multiple context calls get get data in separate tasks concurrently).

Comment: Thank you for all your responses, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better solution could be to separate your projects, you are going to have two different contexts, one created for the Web app and other for the console part.

The problem is the life cycles, while transient and singleton are natural for almost any app, the problem comes with the Scoped type, since it needs something to limit their lifetime, you have two options that I know:

- One is to add the EF context as transient, but be aware, since attached objects will not be able to have the same context, each service class will become a unit of work where the context cannot be shared in other calls
- The other is leave the context as scoped, and define the lifecycle wherever you need with the help of the `IScopedProvider` interface, this way you can create you own Scopes, this way you can limit how the context cache will be shared (everything inside that context will share the same context, taking advantage of the cache and management of attached objects. It looks something like this:

  public class Bar()
  {
      public Bar(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
      {
          using(var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
          {
              // Use the scope to ask for services, they will
              // share the same scope
              scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<>();
          }
      }
  }

To keep things clear I like to use the scopeFactory to ask for a service that will do all the job, this way this service can inject the context and other services and everyone will be sharing the same context, as if it were the same request in the web app.

I like to use like this:

```
public class MainClassInConsoleNoContext()
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
    public MainClassInConsoleNoContext(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public void MyMainAction() {
        using(var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {   
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyServiceWithContextAndScope>().MyScopedAction();           
        }
    }
}


public class MyServiceWithContextAndScope()
{
    private readonly CoreContext _context;

    public MainClassInConsoleNoContext(CoreContext context, OtherService other)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void MyScopedAction() {
        // Here I can use other service, if they both use CoreContext,
        // will be the same in all services, since they share the same
        // scope
    }
}
```

Comment: A comment on why the -1 would be more useful, but thanks!

Comment: You forgot the main problem of question: Caching of data per DbContext! what is the advantage of your solution? At best, instead of declaring DbContext you declared completely new scope per context which has more overhead than creating just DbContext!

Comment: To keep inline with the design of the app, each action is their own unit of work, this give you control to use the scoped lifecycle in the console app, in our case this helps this way: 1-The generic host calls an action each hour, this action creates the context and calls our first service 2.- This service call some services, one of those is a user profile that must be loaded each time the process is run, but the same data is keep loaded as is declared as scoped, so it can be reused in other parts of the process, at the same time now we can share even attached object between services.

Comment: Although my question has been closed, I have marked this as the answer in that it has solved my issue. Wrapping my polling code within a using statement and getting the instances of the services via the scoped serviceprovider is now giving the desired behaviour.  One thing that strikes me generally though is that although EF Core works seamlessly out of the box with ASP.NET Core as by it's nature works as discrete requests, outside of that context there appear to be some 'gotchas' such as this that can creep up on you if multiple process manipulate the same data. Many thanks @rekiem87