# transaction parallel c# when using multiple transactions, they do not pass the duplicate check

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm running a db synchronization method in parallel

```
    var dependedRules = clients.Select(x => SynchronizationPipeLine(x.Key,_scopeFactory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>()));
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(dependedRules, async (r, _) => await r);
```

inside the basic synchronization method, I make a transaction

```
using (var transaction = await _unitOfWork.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Check if the project is in the database, if not, add it before
                        if (!await _unitOfWork.BaseRepositories.ProjectRepository.CheckIfRecordExists(resultProject.ProjectId))
                        {
                            resultProject.Id = await _unitOfWork.BaseRepositories.ProjectRepository.AddAsync(resultProject);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // if there is a record, we find it including links
                            var projectResult = await _unitOfWork.BaseRepositories.ProjectRepository.GetByProjectId(resultProject.ProjectId);
                            resultProject = projectResult;
                        }
                        await _unitOfWork.BaseRepositories.ProjectRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
                        await transaction.CommitAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                    }
                }



im using unitOfWork

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context,
            ILogger<UnitOfWork> logger, rep, rep2)
        {
            _dbContext = context;
            _logger = logger;
            rep= rep;
            BaseRepositories = baseRepositories;
            rep2= rep2;
        }

        public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            _dbContext.UpdatedChangedAtDateTimestamps();
            try
            {   
                return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e, "An error occurred while saving changes");
                throw;
            }
        }

        public IDbContextTransaction BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel? isolationLevel)
        {
            return _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel.Value);
        }

        public async Task<IDbContextTransaction> BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel? isolationLevel)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(isolationLevel.Value);
        }
```

and baseClassRep

```
 public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        protected readonly PerformanceRiskAnalyzerDbContext DbContext;
        protected readonly DbSet<T> DbSet;

        public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            DbContext = dbContext;
            DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll() 
        {
            return await DbSet.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
         
        }

        public async Task<long> AddAsync(T entity)
        {
        
                var entry = await DbSet.AddAsync(entity);
                return entry.Entity.Id;
       
        }

        public async Task<bool> Update(T entity)
        {
        
             DbSet.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                return true;
          
        }

        public async Task AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
        {
            await DbSet.AddRangeAsync(entities);
         
        }

        public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Dependencies reg AddScoped
and
one conext is used.

The essence of the problem when executing transactions, an error occurs in the database for duplicates (it happens) the user is repeated) which I add to the database and after 1 transaction everything is ok 2 may fall due to duplicates. Although the check is where I pull all users out of the database, but as if - in another thread does not know about new users

`var user = await DbContext.Users.Include(x => x.Projects).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId && x.Projects.Any(y=>y.Id == projectId));
if(user != null)
return;

```
     var sqlString = $@"INSERT INTO public.""UserAndProject""(""ProjectsId"", ""UsersId"") VALUES ({projectId}, {userId}) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING";
     var sql = FormattableStringFactory.Create(sqlString);
     await DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync(sql);`
```

this happens when SaveChangesAsync

tried different transactions scoped and restrictions didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you are using a unit of work, you need to be careful about the lifecycle of the Db Context, since it is scoped and can cause issues with parallel processes, since it is not thread safe and ends up being shared by the parallel processes.

Check if this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61841263/1402237

In short, create a scope for each process

```
public class MainClassInConsoleNoContext()
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
    public MainClassInConsoleNoContext(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public void MyMainAction() {
        using(var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {   
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyServiceWithContextAndScope>().MyScopedAction();           
        }
    }
}
```

A good practice would be to create a new service that does your operation, separated from the parallel tasks, then use the scope inside the parallel run so it generates a new scope for each process

```
var dependedRules = clients.Select(x => SynchronizationPipeLine(x.Key,_scopeFactory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>()));
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(dependedRules, async (r, _) => {
    using(var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {   
        await scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyServiceWithContextAndScope>().MyScopedAction();           
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

If you have issues with concurrency, just embrace the database validation, remove your code where you validate if exists or not. Just try to save the entity in a separate transaction, you do not need any particular isolation level, be sure to commit the transaction, if it fails because of a duplicate key just ignore the error and move on.

In a separate transaction then query the model again, you know it must exist because the previous transaction should have created the entity or failed because it already existed.

This would save you the first query you do to validate if it exists, but you would need to query the entity in the second transaction always so you can work with the entity.

Another option is to use a native query so you use something like `INSERT IGNORE` or [similar](https://sebhastian.com/mysql-insert-if-not-exists/)

Comment: Hello @rekiem87, yes, indeed, if you do it through pulling out of scope service and action, errors have become much less common with save in bd when duplicating data. The question is, do you know what is the best way to choose the transaction isolation level (IsolationLevel), given that different threads can climb into the same table both to select and update it.